# os.system error: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

I'm trying to copy files to a new directory using python, and to do so, I set up two os variables $path1 and $path2 as follows:

```
os.environ['path1'] = '<filename>'
os.environ['path2'] = '<dirname/filename2>'
os.system['cp $path1 $path2']
```

This gives me "builtin_function_mor_method' object has no attribute '*getitem*' each time. I've seen almost identical syntax online and have used it, so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You want `os.system('cp $path1 $path2')`.  Notice the parenthesis, not brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function incorrectly:

```
os.system('cp $path1 $path2')
```

That is, you want `()`, not `[]`. `[]` is for getting items from an iterable, `()` is for calling a function like in your case.

Comment: That was stupid of me, I just followed what I had for os.environ

Comment: @user1815498 Don't call yourself stupid, I'm not even joking there. We all make stupid mistakes. If my answer was helpful to you, would you mind accepting it after the fifteen minute grace period has passed? You can do it by clicking on the tick below the vote counts so it turns green. Thank you.

Comment: @glglgl I said getting, not assigning.

Comment: @AlexThornton You know what I mean: as well, not all support item retrieval. Have a look at generators, file objects etc., and they all don't support item access, but iteration.